# How to install a python package without setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setup.py

How to install this python package?

https://github.com/Substancia/FDTD-Huygens-metasurface

in the examples in the repository it refers to:

```py
from fdtd_venv import fdtd_mod as fdtd
```

but it is not clear how to install `fdtd_venv` this package.

Comment: [Please read the official documentation on how to install Python packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/)

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect any arbitrary Python code you find on GitHub to be properly designed for installation, or **intended** for installation. In Python, we install *packages* in order to have *libraries* of reusable code. You appear to have found a project that is intended to run as stand-alone. It does not offer an installer because there is nothing to install. You are not meant to be able to `import` anything from it meaningfully; it's just a script that can be run. Therefore, there is no particular reason to put its files in any particular location.

Comment: It's also not clear **what you hope to accomplish** by "installing" the code. Further: "in the examples in the repository" - I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Finally, just to make sure: you **do** know that Python 2.7 is **past end of life and will not receive any maintenance, even for critical security fixes, and has been like this for more than three years**? The project that you link is newer than that, so it is unlikely that it is actually intended to be run with Python 2.7. That version of Python is as far out of date as Windows 7.